# Avoid printing empty views/areas in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am printing a sheet from a excel file as a pdf. This sheet is having multiple views/area. I have to print only few views which contains data and do not want to print the views which are blank. I already set print area for all the views. Blank views will have data in future hence I am not allow to remove them.

In current scenario, I am getting blank space for the empty views when I print, which I need to avoid. I tried various VBA macros but didn't have any luck yet.

Comment: A way around could be to filter the blanks away, before print.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. If you're working on VBA code, please include it.